# How to save in database multiple rows input with c#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to insert name and address of three persons at the same time in database. How is it possible.

Comment: Either use a `for` loop in c# or use a stored procedure in sql

Comment: It is possible by writing code.

Comment: What SQL library are you using? ADO.Net. EntityFramework, Dapper, ... What did you try already and what is the problem? Show us some of your code please.

Comment: I am using c#.net with SQL server database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for Multiple insert at a time :

INSERT INTO MyTable  (FirstCol, SecondCol)
    SELECT  'First' ,1
    UNION ALL
SELECT  'Second' ,2
    UNION ALL
SELECT  'Third' ,3
...
Please refer below link for more clarification on same :

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/